# Как загрузить картинку на сайт через JSOUP

Tags: android, post, изображения, jsoup

Использую JSOUP и хочу загрузить картинку на сайт.
При отправке запроса на сайт в консоли разработчика хрома появляются такие заголовки

```
Request payload:

------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="installation_problem_form"

installation_problem_form
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="installation_problem_form-information-meassure_damage_kind_focus"


------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="installation_problem_form-information-meassure_damage_kind_input"


------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="installation_problem_form-information-j_idt183"

бла-бла-бла

------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="installation_problem_form-information_activeIndex"

2
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.ViewState"

-5639715958586783947:2893671246192400114
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.partial.ajax"

true
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.partial.execute"

installation_problem_form-information-j_idt258
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.source"

installation_problem_form-information-j_idt258
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.partial.render"

installation_problem_form-information-att_table
------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="installation_problem_form-information-j_idt258"; filename="тест.bmp"
Content-Type: image/bmp


------WebKitFormBoundary3SE46lGTAJLz5z2K--
```

Смотрю я на них и не вижу, где же сам мой файл. Или я что то не так начинаю делать?

Comment: при отправк**е** запроса! слово отправк**и** отвечает на вопрос чего?. при отправк**е** - на вопрос когда. Вы же говорите "при ходьб**е**",  а не "при ходьб**ы**"

Comment: Вы, судя по всему, смотрите не в тот инструмент консоли разработчика

Comment: @metalurgus досадная ошибка, какой конфуз. А куда смотреть? при нажатии кнопки "загрузить" на сайте во вкладке network появляется POST запрос XHR ну и всякая чепуха в виде еще 4 пост запросов с кодом 204 (no content) и вообще без заголовков

Comment: Покажите страницу, на которой находится форма, как минимум

Comment: @metalurgus к сожалению, она находится в интрасети

Comment: Тогда покажите код формы, например, в которую загружается файл